# Jquery - IF-ELSE logic doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to write a jquery function that controls user input of a texfield (for currency) based on locale. The alert did tell me that the german locale is "de". But the if-else logic does not work. The preventDefault() for the specific keycodes work just fine without the if-else. Can someone please tell me what it is that i am doing wrong here?

```
     jQuery(function($) {
             $('.currency').on('keydown', function(e) {
               var locale = $('#currFormat').val(); 
               //alert(locale); 

               if (locale.toLowerCase() === "de" ) {                    
                  console.log(e.keyCode);

                 if (e.keyCode !== 46 && e.keyCode > 31 && e.keyCode !== 96 && e.keyCode !== 97 && e.keyCode !== 98 && e.keyCode !== 99 && e.keyCode !== 100 && e.keyCode !== 101 && e.keyCode !== 102 && e.keyCode !== 103 && e.keyCode !== 104 && e.keyCode !== 105 && e.keyCode !== 188 e.keyCode !== 37 && e.keyCode !==39 && (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) {
                    //stop all non-numbers
                    e.preventDefault();

                } else {
                 // Here goes logic for not allowing comma and others (,)
              }
             });
           });
```

The 'amount' value comes from the JSP.

```
    <input type="hidden" id="CurrFormat" name="currFormat" 
     value="${pageContext.request.locale.language}" />
```

Comment: What is the second console logs output?

Comment: So that was the keycodes that I had in there and the console shows a syntax error in the JS. It points to that particular if statement that I just edited with. Although, it worked to me earlier before I added the if-else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. So technically you are selecting the element that is not present on the page.

```
$('#currFormat').val();
```

is supposed to be

```
$('#CurrFormat').val();
```

Also is this a copy paste error as well

```
e.keyCode !== 188 e.keyCode !== 37  --> missing logical && between expressions
```

Also the reason it is easy to make a syntax error is because the code is not readable at all. Instead you can condense it and make it simpler.

```
var keyCode = e.keyCode;
var invalidKeyCodes = [37, 39, 46, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101. 102, 103, 104, 105, 188];

if (invalidKeyCodes.indexOf(keyCode) < 0 && keyCode > 31 && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57)) {
```

Comment: Sorry that typo was made while posting the question. I have the correct id in my code.

Comment: `e.keyCode !== 188 e.keyCode !== 37` ? is this copy paste issue ?

Comment: You are right! I had a 110 or 190 for period(.) for US when it worked. I changed that to 188 for comma (,) for Germany. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @MonsoonThunder Check the edited post. It would then be lot easier to find bugs when it is readable.

Comment: @Sushanth-- That makes sense. Thank you!